# Add two values in dictionary parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have to use the masterkey to write to another user to store values in a column in the parse class. The column holds a dictionary, where the first value is a id `var chatDialogId = request.params.chatID;` and the second value is 0 or 1.

When the value is first being created is when the object created we set the second value to 1.

I get the id for the first value from the request.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addFriendToFriendsRelation", function(request, response) {

    var friendRequestId = request.params.Friends;

    var chatDialogId = request.params.chatID;

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    query.get(friendRequestId, {
        useMasterKey: true, 
        success: function(friendRequest) {

            var fromUser = friendRequest;
            var toUser = request.user; 
            var relation = fromUser.relation("Friends");

            // notification is the dictionary column... 
            var notification = fromUser.get("notification");
            //WHICH WAY??? 

            //notification.push????

            //notification.put?????


            relation.add(toUser);

            fromUser.save(null, {
                useMasterKey: true, 
                success: function() {
                    response.success("saved relation and updated friendRequest");
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    response.error(error);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

The fromUser is the user we found from the user query and where we want to update the notification dictionary.

Comment: i have a column in user table that  is a dictionary, the chatID is being passed in the request which i will use to save to the dictionary along with the second value being "1". this is for the "fromUser" in this code, which is the user found as the result of the query. i want to put those to values together in the dictionary and push it. this is the "notification" column so i created a variable that is called "notification"

Comment: and what do you want from us?... you got my permission to do it :-)

Comment: i do not know how to do this in javascript/cloud code. to save to values to a dictionary.

Comment: to my knowledge parse DB doesnt support dictionary as a type, you can use arrays though

Comment: I want to add a two key value pairs in an array so chat id and "1" ... Do u know how to do this in JavaScript

Comment: @kareem did you find an answer to it?